# You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. When running docker-compose up locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

New to docker, I have been trying to use it with my rails project but haven't been able to start it up.

Tried changing ruby versions, and searching the web, but most questions involved deploying the app to heroku, which is not my case.

Docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1
RUN mkdir /zssn
WORKDIR /zssn
COPY Gemfile /zssn/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /zssn/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle --version
RUN bundle install
COPY . /zssn

CMD ["rails", "server"]
```

docker-compose-yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/zssn
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

docker build . --no-cache, seems to be working fine when running the bundler command to install it.

```
 ---> Running in d4650608f428
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding this line before RUN bundle install to the Dockerfile did the trick for me.

```
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
```

Leaving this here for future reference!

Comment: This did not work for me... Any suggestion? I locally created the project with bundler 2.1.4 and specified the same version on Dockerfile as well as a gem update --system before.

Answer (score 7):

You need to update Rubygems:

```
RUN gem update --system
```

Apart of being sure that you have the correct bundler version, run:

```
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
```

[Here](https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html#prerequisites) you can find a deeply explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby image comes with installed `bundler`.
Environment variable `BUNDLER_VERSION` is set to preinstalled version of `bundler` by default. Even if you uninstall this version, `bundle` will check for this environment variable and
raise error "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile" if there is a v1/v2 mismatch

Ensure that your `Gemfile.lock` bundled with needed version:

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

If you have another version, you can upgrade your application to the latest installed version of Bundler by running `bundle update --bundler` https://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html

In `Dockerfile` override environment variable `BUNDLER_VERSION` to needed version of bundler and install it:

```
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.1.4

RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:2.1.4 && \
    bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

in your Gemfile.lock, at the bottom, you may find bundle version:

```
BUNDLED WITH
2.0.1
```

Please make sure you bundled it with the correct version that you have

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to either upgrade to a ruby image that comes with bundler 2 (e.g. `FROM ruby:2.6.3`) or rebundle your `Gemfile.lock` with the bundler version you want to use. Or at least that's what worked for me.

It did not work to tweak the environment variables as suggested by the [Bundler guides](https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_docker_guide.html).

This [github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/pull/255) makes me think this is expected behavior, but I could be totally wrong.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Tried, but still had no luck.